# How to transform summary statistics count into integers on pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I'm running into the following issue.

I have pulled some summary statistics from a dataframe, using `pd.describe()`.  Now, I'm trying to convert the number of observations (or count) into an integer. I've used the following but it does not work:

```
summary_stats = df.describe()
summary_stats = summary_stats.round(2)
summary_stats.iloc[0] = summary_stats.iloc[0].astype(int)
```

Then, when I print out the summary statistics table, the number of observations is not an integer. Thanks a lot for your insights!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is problem, because floats with integers in same column. So integers are converted to floats.

Possible solution with transpose - then column has integer `dtype`:

```
d = {'A':[1,2,3,4,5], 'B':[2,2,2,2,2], 'C':[3,3,3,3,3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

summary_stats = df.describe().T
summary_stats = summary_stats.round(2)
summary_stats['count'] = summary_stats['count'].astype(int)
print (summary_stats)
   count  mean   std  min  25%  50%  75%  max
A      5   3.0  1.58  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0
B      5   2.0  0.00  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0
C      5   3.0  0.00  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0  3.0
```

If need only display values, here is hack - converted values to `object`:

```
summary_stats = df.describe()
summary_stats = summary_stats.round(2).astype(object)
summary_stats.iloc[0] = summary_stats.iloc[0].astype(int)
print (summary_stats)
         A    B    C
count     5    5    5
mean    3.0  2.0  3.0
std    1.58  0.0  0.0
min     1.0  2.0  3.0
25%     2.0  2.0  3.0
50%     3.0  2.0  3.0
75%     4.0  2.0  3.0
max     5.0  2.0  3.0
```

Comment: Suppose that I want to further edit the names "count", "mean", "std", etc. into "N", "Mean" and "St. Dev.". I have a multi-index so I cannot really reset index and then replace string names. Is there an efficient way to do so? Thanks..

Comment: @Dorito0102 Use `.rename(index={'count':'N'},level=0)` if multiindex in index and need rename first level. For second level use  `.rename(index={'count':'N'},level=1)`. If MultiIndex in columns use  `.rename(columns={'count':'N'},level=0)` or  `.rename(columns={'count':'N'},level=1)`